# How to populate values from Doctrine FindAll() result

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to build chart where data coming from database dynamically.
So far, I can display this chart by creating a dummy data stored in array.

controller

```
//dummy data
$data = array(
        array('OFW', 45.0),
        array('Mindanao', 26.8),
        array('Visayas', 12.8),
        array('Luzon', 8.5),
    );
```

Now I want to fill those values with the real values from a database.I am using Doctrine2 for this project

```
 $island = $em->getRepository('DuterteBundle:Island')->findAll();
 foreach($island as $is) { return $is }
 //where $is = island1, island2, island3
```

Then I refactor the previous dummy data like

```
  $data = array(array($is, 67));

  return $this->render('Bundle:.........);
```

This code will only display the graph with only one $is value.In this case the island1.What is the proper way to display all values?

update

I refactor my code so..

```
// controller
 $island = $em->getRepository('DuterteBundle:Island')->createQueryBuilder('i')
       ->orderBy('i.name', 'ASC')
       ->getQuery()
       ->getResult();
    $island_names = array();//initialise array
        foreach ($island as $is) {
            $island_names[] = array(
                'name' => $is->getName()
            );
        }   

  $val = array();
    foreach ($island_names as $key) {
        $val = $key['name'];
    }
    $data = array(array($val,56.78));
```

dumping data

```
 echo '<pre>';
    \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($data);
    echo '</pre>';
```

results in

```
 array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "Visayas"
      [1]=>
     float(56.78)
  }
}
```

Update
I refactor my code again

```
 $island = $em->getRepository('DuterteBundle:Island')->createQueryBuilder('i')
       ->orderBy('i.name', 'ASC')
       ->getQuery()
       ->getResult();
    $datas = array();//initialise array
        foreach ($island as $is) {
            $datas[] = array(
                'name' => $is->getName(),
                'id' => 100
            );
        }
```

Now dumping the data will show all expected results

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Luzon"
      ["id"]=>
      int(100)
 }
  [1]=>
    array(2) {
     ["name"]=>
     string(8) "Mindanao"
     ["id"]=>
        int(100)
  }
  [2]=>
    array(2) {
     ["name"]=>
     string(3) "OFW"
       ["id"]=>
       int(100)
 }
 [3]=>
    array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
      string(7) "Visayas"
        ["id"]=>
        int(100)
  }
}
```

Now the remaining problem is to populate to an array which is needed by chart

The dummy data looks like this

```
$data = array(
        array('OFW', 45.0),
        array('Mindanao', 26.8),
        array('Visayas', 12.8),
        array('Luzon', 8.5),
    );
```

I tried to replace with real values like this

```
 $data = array(array($datas));
```

The chart in template doesn't show.I can see the dumped values.

Update

Whole code inside the Graph Controller

```
public function graphAction(Request $request)
{
    //we will count all voters here
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $voters = $em->getRepository('DuterteBundle:Voters')->findAll();
    $voters_count = count($voters);

    $ob = new Highchart();
    $ob->chart->renderTo('piechart');
    $ob->title->text("Island/OFW voter's shares"." ".(number_format($voters_count))."total votes as of " . date('F d,Y h:i A')."/Asia-Manila Time");
    $ob->plotOptions->pie(array(
        'allowPointSelect'  => true,
        'cursor'    => 'pointer',
        'dataLabels'    => array('enabled' => false),
        'showInLegend'  => true
    ));

    $island = $em->getRepository('DuterteBundle:Island')->createQueryBuilder('i')
       ->orderBy('i.name', 'ASC')
       ->getQuery()
       ->getResult();
    $datas = array();//initialise array
        foreach ($island as $is) {
            $datas[] = array(
                'name' => $is->getName(),
                'id' => 100
            );
        }
     echo '<pre>';
    \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($datas);
    echo '</pre>';
    $data = array(array($datas));//the problem is here

    //with this dummy data, the chart/graph will work

    /*$data = array(//how to replace this with real datas?
        array('OFW', 45.0),
        array('Mindanao', 26.8),
        array('Visayas', 12.8),
        array('Luzon', 8.5),
    );*/
    $series = array(
        array('type' => 'pie','name' => "Voter's share", 'data' => $data)
    );
    $ob->series($series);
    return $this->render('GraphBundle:Default:graph.html.twig', array(
        'chart' => $ob,
        'votercount' => $voters_count
    ));

}
```

Comment: Is there values in db as well? Just simply: `$data = array(); foreach ($island as $is) { $data[] = array($is->getName(), $is->getValue()); }`

Comment: I am still working to count values in db.Island table has name and id column.It is related to voters entity where island has many voters and voters has one Island.The values i want to display is the the count of voters per island.Maybe I achieve that in join query

Comment: I don't understand your problem, you're doing `$val=$name['key']` this way `$val` will **always** have the name of the **last** island.

Comment: So you have many names in results, like 'island1','island1','island2'...?

Comment: @malcomn yes, I expect many names in result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have many names in results and want to count them, you can use [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) PHP function:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($island as $is) {
    $data[] = $is->getName();
};

$data = array_count_values($data);
```

and if you want format it as described:

```
$results = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $results[] = array($key, $value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it.I change the foreach loop to

```
$datas = array();//initialise array
        foreach ($island as $is) {
            $datas[] = array(
                $is->getName(),100
            );
        }
```

as suggested by user malcolm